# Not able to get updated mouse position without clicking

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm making a simple game using Pygame. I have embedded the the Pygame display into a Tkinter window.

Now, when I execute this - `print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())` It does print the position, but when I move the mouse it doesn't print the updated mouse position. It still prints the previous mouse position unless I click on the display.

This didn't happen with the same program before embedding the Pygame display into a Tkinter window.
So, the event system doesn't seem to work properly.

Someone suggested that, you could detect the events in Tkinter and then forward them to Pygame. But, I'm not sure how I'm going to implement that.

How do I go about this? I would really appreciate some help here. Thank You!

Comment: Do you handel the events (`pygame.event.get()`) in the application loop?

Comment: You can check `pygame.MOUSEMOTION` event in the loop.

Comment: Yes, I have defined it in a function and I call it in the main while loop

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the current position of the mouse, you can use a library called **pynput**. This library allows you to monitor and control the keyboard and the mouse. To track the mouse you can use the following code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller

mouse = Controller()
current_pos = mouse.position
```